# What are the limitations for bookmark names in Microsoft Word?

Tags: ms-word, bookmarks

I need to bookmark parts of a document from the name of paragraphs but the name of a paragraph is not always a valid name for a bookmark name. I have not found on Google or MSDN an exhaustive list of limitations for bookmark names.

What special characters are forbidden?

The only thing I found is that the length must not exceed 40 characters.

Comment: This may be of interest to passers by, how to add a ` . ` to a bookmark in MS Word: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51868419/3451115

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you are familiar with regular expressions, I would say it is

```
^(?!\d)\w{1,40}$
```

Where `\w` refers to the range of Unicode word characters, which also contain the underscore and the digits from 0-9.

In plain English: The bookmark name must...

- be between 1 and 40 characters long
- consist of any combination of Unicode letters, digits, underscores
- *not* start with a digit
- *not* contain any kind of white space or punctuation

As stated in the comments, bookmark names beginning with an underscore are treated as *hidden*. They will not appear in the regular user interface, but they can be used from VBA code. It it is not possible to create bookmarks that begin with an underscore via the regular user interface, but you can do it through VBA code with `Bookmarks.Add()`.

Comment: +1, Plus that bookmarks whose name begins with '_' are treated as hidden.

Comment: That would lead us to "^(_|\w)[\w\d]{0,39}$"

Comment: @Maxime Vernier: "_" is traditionally part of "\w".

Comment: @divo: I actually failed to create a bookmark that begins with "_" in Word 2003...

Comment: @Tomalak: I have checked the meaning of \w on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expressions and it seems \d is part of \w too. 

I would say "^[_A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]{0,39}$"

- starts with an underscore or a letter
- then at most 39 letters or digits

Comment: @Tomalak: I cannot create a bookmark that begins with "_" in Word 2000 or 2003. It should be possible with the API though.

Comment: You can have underscores within the name. Rules: 1. starts with an underscore or a letter, 2. followed with at most 39 letters, digits or underscores.
^[_A-Za-z]\w{0,39}$

Comment: Maxime Vernier: You are right - \d is part of \w. I'll reformulate the Regular expression. :)

Comment: @Maxime Vernier: I refer to \w instead of "A-Z" because word characters from foreign languages are explicitly allowed. You may create Hebrew bookmarks, or Chinese ones, for example.

Comment: @Tomalak: I have trouble reading your last rexexp ^(?!\d)\w{1,40}$.
For me it means starts with an optional character (any character: .) except \d. Since we want \w minus \d, it catches more things than needed and it can match strings of length 41. How about ^[_A-Za-z]\w{0,39}$ instead?

Comment: The regular expression contains of a so-called "negative zero-width assertion" (?!\d) meaning "a position not followed by a digit", and 1-40 "word characters". This special construct is necessary because \w{1,40} would allow a string that *begins* with a digit. Your regex would force the first character to be in the A-Z range, but in fact many more characters than this are legal. My variant allows them all.

Comment: I understand the "negative zero-width assertion" now. My regexp is ascii only, yours is unicode thus better. Thanks to both of you for your help.

Comment: As mentioned above bookmarks starting with an underscore are marked as hidden. Make sure to set the ShowHidden boolean to true on the bookmarks collection to be able to enumerate them.