# How to add . to a name of a bookmark in Word

Tags: ms-word

So i am using Word to create a template for the generation of a .pdf using XDocReport in Java. The problem i have encountered is that when i add a bookmark to an image in Word the allowed names cannot contain "."  , for example i cannot name the bookmark estimate2.Photo , which is the name needed to correctly map the variable to the virtual object being passed. My question is the following, is there any way i can alter this default Word behaviour in order for it to allow me to add bookmarks that contain special characters like "." ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found a way to rewire this default behaviour by modifying the configuration .xml files. In order to access the bookmarks file follow these steps:

1. Go to the .docx file right-click on it go to 7zip and open as archive.
2. Access the word folder and there you will find the document.xml file.
3. extract it
4. Open with notepad or any other text editor,  find the bookmark start xml tag which contains the name property and modify it.
5. Once the file has been modified drag it back inside the archive and save.

Comment: And did you actually try to OPEN and use a file you've modified in such a manner?

Comment: yeah , I reinserted the file in the zip and afterwards when i opened the project with Word i could see my custom bookmark in the list of bookmarks

Comment: Interesting. I'd have bet it couldn't work. In that case, if you needed it, you could probably do it withint the Word application, as well, using Range.WordOpenXML, add the bookmark to that, then Range.InsertXML to replace the Range and add the bookmark with it.

Comment: @CindyMeister - just tested the idea, yes... Range.InsertXML works!

Answer (score 2):

## Wow. I wouldn't have thought this would work... Nice find @Patratel

> not withstanding the fact that it seems to work, I wouldn't recommend doing this for anything other than a temporary file or curiosity...

That said, here's the steps to do / test this:

### The manual approach:

1. Add a regular bookmark (shortcut: Alt > I > K)

   - give it a name like dot_dot
   - save the file
   - change the extension from .docx to .zip
2. open the .zip folder

   - save document.xml to the desktop (or somewhere)
3. Find the text dot_dot and replace with dot.dot

   - save .xml file
   - copy .xml file back to .zip folder
   - rename .zip back to .docx
4. Open in MS Word

   - open bookmarks dialog (Alt > I > K)
   - select dot.dot from list
   - press Goto

[image: How to add a dot bookmark]

#### A quick test of functionality

From there it is easy enough to test whether or not the bookmark can be used as normal... To that end I added a new paragraph and inserted a cross reference back to the bookmarked text. The cross reference worked.

### The .InsertXML approach

Next I was also curious about @Cindy's comment about Range insert XML... It worked, to test this I used the following code in the immediate window:

```
' replace text in document with the equivalent XML (generates a few pages)
selection.Range.Text = thisdocument.Range.WordOpenXML

' replace the XML with the result of inserting itself into the document
thisdocument.Range.InsertXML thisdocument.Range.Text
```

### An Automatic Approach

```
Sub dottyBM()
    Dim newDoc As Word.Document
    Set newDoc = Application.Documents.Add
    newDoc.Range.Text = "Testing a dot bookmark"

    Dim bmRange As Word.Range
    Set bmRange = newDoc.Paragraphs(1).Range
    bmRange.Start = bmRange.Start + InStr(bmRange.Text, " dot")
    bmRange.End = bmRange.Start + 3

    ' bmRange.Bookmarks.Add "dot.dot"  ' Err: 5828, Bad bookmark name
    bmRange.Bookmarks.Add "dot_dot"
    bmRange.InsertXML Replace$(bmRange.WordOpenXML, "dot_dot", "dot.dot")
    Application.Dialogs(168).Show

    newDoc.Close False
End Sub
```